# What does this Ruby code do? unvisited_cities.min do |city|

Tags: ruby

I am working through a book on algorithms and it contains a description of Dijkstra's algorithm with a code sample in Ruby. The code solves a hypothetical problem of finding the cheapest flight path from city A to city B. You cannot necessarily fly directly from A to B, and so there may be multiple flights required to complete your trip.

A `City` object has a `@name` that is a String and `@routes` that is a hash with a City object as the key and ticket price as the value.

For example, the city of Atlanta is defined by

```
atlanta = City.new("Atlanta")
atlanta.add_route(boston, 100)
atlanta.add_route(denver, 160)
# where the add_route method states that 
@routes[city] = price
```

Further, `unvisited_cities` is an array of `City` objects, and `cheapest_prices_table` is a hash with a city `@name` as the key and ticket price as the value.

**My question is**, what does the following code, which is part of the Dijkstra algorithm code sample, do? I am unfamiliar with the syntax `unvisited_cities.min do |city|`. I placed a `puts` statement just above the code in question (`p unvisited_cities.min`), and I received an error: `ArgumentError (comparison of City with City failed)`. I could not find a description of this syntax anywhere to understand exactly what the lines below do. That is, how does the code below set `current_city` to be the least expensive city to fly to in `unvisited_cities`?

```
# We visit our next unvisited city. We choose the one that is cheapest
# to get to from the STARTING city:
current_city = unvisited_cities.min do |city|
  cheapest_prices_table[city.name]
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: "could not find a description of this syntax anywhere to understand exactly what the lines below do" [`Array#min`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Array.html#method-i-min) "I tried, and this array does not respond to the `.min` method" Why do you believe this to be true? How did you "try"?

Comment: @engineersmnky I guess "does not respond to the .min method" is incorrect. It does not respond nicely is what I should have said. I placed a `puts` statement before the `current_cities = ...` statement (`p unvisited_cities.min`) and the output is `ArgumentError (comparison of City with City failed)`. I will update the wording of the question.

Comment: @engineersmnky Also, note that the `unvisited_cities` array on its own would have no knowledge of prices, it is just a collection of `City` objects.

Comment: That is due to precedence. `do...end` has a lower precedence than the method call so this is parsed as `p(current_city = unvisited_cities.min) do`. `min` called without a block uses `<=>` (referred to as the spaceship operator) to compare each element but `City` is not comparable (does not implement `<=>`). To solve this error either print the result afterwords or wrap the call along with the entire block in parens e.g. `p(current_city = unvisited_cities.min do |city|
  cheapest_prices_table[city.name]
end)`

Comment: In contrast I assume `cheapest_prices_table[city.name]`(called in each iteration of the block) returns a numeric of some kind. These objects do implement `<=>` and as such they can be compared accordingly so as to determine the minimum value.

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks for that explanation. I'll take a look at this more closely to see if I can make sense of it and report back.